# RxJava2. Как вернуть Observable<Object> из метода, который возвращает void?

Tags: rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Метод `takePicture(...)` из `android.hardware.Camera` имеет тип возвращаемого значения `void`

```
public final void takePicture(ShutterCallback shutter, PictureCallback raw, PictureCallback jpeg) {
   takePicture(shutter, raw, null, jpeg);
}
```

Как реализовать возврат `Observable<Bitmap>` из `Camera.PictureCallback`? Использую RxJava2.

```
public Observable<Bitmap> getBitmap() {
   camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
         return data; // <<< ???
      }
   });
}
```

P.S. Я не стал писать код, где перевожу data в bitmap, думаю это к делу не относится. Можно пример с любым возвращаемым типом.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Observable<Bitmap> getBitmap() {
   ReplaySubject<Bitmap> subject = ReplaySubject.create();
   camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length);
         subject.onNext(bitmap);
      }
   });
   return subject;
}
```

Comment: Сергей, спасибо за ответ. Я первый раз вижу ReplaySubject, можете объяснить или дать ссылку где я могу понять разницу между ReplaySubject.create() и Observable.create()? Если это имеет какое то значение, я использую io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.16.

Comment: [ReplaySubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/ReplaySubject.html) - это наследник `Observable`, позволяющий публиковать события. Почитать можно [тут](https://medium.com/@poudanen/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-rxjava-subject-publish-replay-behavior-%D0%B8-async-subject-35ad50cd1064) например.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел пример, переписал под свои нужны, все работает, получаю bitmap. Но я практически не понимаю внутреннего устройства RxJava2 (пока еще сложно для меня). Я точно не вспомню, но не раз читал, что с RxJava нужно быть аккуратным, т.к. можно получить какие то ошибки или что то может пойти не так (что именно не вспомню). Верно ли то, что я написал. Могут ли быть какие то грабли?

```
public Observable<Bitmap> takePicture() {
   return Observable.create(emitter -> {
      try {
         camera.takePicture(null, null, (data, camera) -> {
            emitter.onNext(convert(data));
            emitter.onComplete(); // №1 необходимо ли это?
         });
      } catch (Exception e) {
         emitter.onError(e);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Так даже лучше, пожалуй. Вызов `onComplete` сигнализирует о том, что больше ничего отправляться не будет. Его стоит использовать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev просто когда я пишу код, я стараюсь понимать полностью как это работает, т.к. от недопонимания можно долго не понимать, почему же все идет не так, как ты хочешь :)... и я не понимаю, какое в данном случае я получу поведение с emitter.onComplete(); и без него.

Comment: Если ваш код на возвращаемый `Observable` не вешает обработчик `onComplete`, то разницы вы можете и не заметить.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev хм... т.е. onComplete нужен только тогда, когда мне необходимо конкретно это событие... например цикл for испускает 0...9 я их получаю и обрабатываю, но не узнаю что цифр больше не будет, с onComplete я знаю, что цифр больше не будет и могу реализовать какую то логику, основанную на этом?